# Отменить изменения make:auth

Tags: laravel

После выполнения команды `make:auth` мое представление `home` заменилось на стандартное. Удалил все связанные с аутентификацией файлы, но перестала загружаться главная страница сайта. В чем может быть причина ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если бы вы использовали git, то без труда смогли бы как отменить, как и посмотреть изменения.

Answer (score 0):

В ошибке же написано, что не найден файл layouts/app.blade.php , которая подключена в вашем файле home.blade.php